# Sinch Client down? Getting unable to resolve host

Tags: android, voip, sinch

After setting up Sinch instant messaging on my app and testing it, it worked good. Now when I try to use it i get: `04-10 00:08:16.175  12082-12103/com.yupo.dominic.yupo E/sinch-android-rtc﹕ Error(code: 1002, domain: network, message: UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "sandbox.sinch.com": No address associated with hostname)`. I'm assuming this is on Sinch's side as the client was working fine yesterday.

Can anyone help if this an error on my side?

Have searched online but cannot find any information regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a problem with your internet connection. Either offline or a flaky internet connection.

Comment: Yea that seems to be the case, sometimes it works, sometimes not